# django-sentry unit tests erroring out of the box

Tags: django, unit-testing

I'd just easy_install'd django-sentry and added it to my project, but when I run the tests with `./manage.py test sentry`, I get 4 failures and 11 errors.

I've added, `indexer`, `paging`, `sentry`, `sentry.client`, and `south` to my `INSTALLED_APPS`, and I can get to http://localhost:8000/sentry/ in a browser (and all seems to be working). Is there more that needs to be done in order have Sentry properly configured?

Answer (score 0):

I have a lot of errors too.

[According to the developer](https://github.com/dcramer/django-sentry/issues/116):

> The problem is simply that we don't
>   require certain dependencies as part
>   of the core INSTALLED_APPS.
>
> We'll need to document the
>   requirements for getting tests to
>   pass, as well as make certain tests
>   only run if conditions are met (e.g.
>   haystack [fork], and celery tests
>   should check for their libraries)